# Update Feature Branch in Git with Raw Source Code

Tags: git, merge, branch

I have my own feature branch that I've added to a code using git. Unfortunately, updates for the main code come frequently, and have no version control. I get raw source code each time.

What is the proper way to update my feature branch with the newer version of the code? I have no history showing how the code was updated...

So: Is there a command to bring in the newer raw source code into the master branch and then automatically merge all files that I have not touched, but that have been updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a branch (called whatever you want, maybe "vendor"), and commit each new version of the source code you get into that branch. Git will figure out what's different between the new code and the previous one, and then you can merge it into your code:

```
git checkout master
git merge vendor
```

It will be easiest if you start with the original source that you started modifying (ie. your first commit into Git), and branch the "vendor" branch from that point.

Comment: Hi Greg! Thanks for the help! So this code has literally thousands of files, many of which will have updates. Is there a way to accept all new changes without having to manually fix each file?

Comment: @NDR: If your vendor source code changes rapidly, you may have merge issues. But this isn't really related to Git - you would have the same problem no matter how you merged your code. Note that when you commit a new load of vendor code, just switch to the vendor branch and add/commit everything that is new. No need to worry about what is different at that point. You're just using Git to help keep track of work somebody else did.

Comment: @NDR, if you never make your own changes directly in the vendor branch, you should be able to just do a `git commit -a` to commit all the changes.  The merge Greg mentioned will bring the new changes into master and only make you fix the conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you have since then an "official" model for managing feature branch with git: **[gitflow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow)**.

See "[Why aren't you using git-flow?](http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2010/why-arent-you-using-git-flow/)"

```
git flow feature rebase
```

would rebase your feature branch on top of the `master` (regularly updated) branch.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `git-load-dirs` tool that seems to be part of **vcs-load-dirs** but is no longer maintained by the author. I know other tools like `git-buildpackage` (for Debian) use `git-load-dirs` to take a source tarball and import it as a new upstream version to create their own history of the upstream releases.

For this to work I believe you need an untouched branch to use as your upstream history, so you either need to use master and never commit your own work to it or use a different branch for the upstream history such as 'upstream'.